# List Item Validation With The Content Type Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, classic-experience

Is it possible to use a validation formula with the content type field?

Something along the lines of:

```
=IF([Content Type]="Project",Status="Closed",IF([Date Closed]=TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

My list has more than one content type and the Date Closed field is not used in all of them.

List settings --> Validation settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible to use the content type field in list validation.

As a workaround, you could create another column and copy cotent type to it.

Comment: If I create a field to mirror the Content Type field, the above code example would work?   I only want the validation to check on some of the Content Types on my list.  Not all of the Content Types in my list have Date Closed associated with them.